Ogr2ogr: How do I filter a .SHP based on multiple attribute values
I'm attempting to convert (to GeoJSON) & filter a .shp file by the value of multiple attributes.
This example, using a single attribute (ID) value, works as expected but I'm confused by the syntax required for multiple examples.
ogr2ogr -f geojson Boundaries.geojson South_West.shp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -where ID=389

Are commas or brackets or OR operators required?
I've tried a sql command instead of -where but with no luck.
-sql "SELECT * FROM South_West.shp WHERE ID IN (389,388)

Edit:
I'm using Gdal version 3.7.1
Source of SQL command:
Selecting features by attributes using ogr2ogr?

You have two different datatypes in the SQL. The first assumes string, and the second integer. What is the actual type?

If you mean the value of ID, the version that works as expected also work without the single quotes around ID'd value, so I presume it's an integer. Otherwise you'll have to expand.
I've added some extra detail to my OP.

With a shapefile as input, you can use any WHERE clause that is supported by OGRSQL: OGRSQL WHERE when using -where.
You should put double quotes around the statement (") so it is parsed as one parameter by gdal.
E.g.:
ogr2ogr -f geojson Boundaries.geojson South_West.shp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -where "ID IN (389,388)"

Using a full SQL statement should work as well, but the table should not have .shp at the end and the command is missing a double quote character (") at the end.
-sql "SELECT * FROM South_West WHERE ID IN (389,388)"

Using an "or" in -where works for me:
$ ogr2ogr -f geojson /tmp/out.geojson $SHP -t_srs EPSG:4326 -where 'osm_id = 4058083 or osm_id = 4058081'

Producing an output geoJSON with just those two features:
$ ogrinfo -so -al /tmp/out.geojson 
INFO: Open of `/tmp/out.geojson'
      using driver `GeoJSON' successful.

Layer name: rivers
Geometry: Line String
Feature Count: 2

$ ogrinfo -al /tmp/out.geojson  | grep osm_id
osm_id: Real (0.0)
  osm_id (Real) = 4058081
  osm_id (Real) = 4058083

Note you do have to quote the expression so it isn't split by the command line into several arguments to ogr2ogr, but gets passed as a single argument to ogr2ogr to deal with. You got away with this in your first example because you had no spaces in ID=389 so it didn't get split. ID = 389 (unquoted) would have errored!

This is baffling:
-where ID=389 works as expected
-where 'ID=389' returns:
`{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "South_West",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
]
}`
-where 'ID = 389' and  -where 'ID = 389 or ID = 388' returns:
ERROR 1: Couldn't fetch requested layer '='!

What operating system are you using? And what command line interpreter/terminal? Maybe Windows' quoting is different to bash on Linux...

Double quotes should work both on Linux and on Windows, but single quotes certainly do not work on Windows. I am not sure if this is documented in any distinct place within GDAL documentation. This looks rather good  https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html#cmdoption-ogr2ogr-select but maybe in this context the question is not about GDAL but about how command line interface works generally on Windows.
